# Redirect previous page after login

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

Although there are some solutions around, I could not get them as a solution for my case.

I need redirect users to the same page instead of myaccount page after they login.

From the login.php;

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "login")
{
    $username   = mysql_real_escape_string(getPostParameter('username'));
    $pwd        = mysql_real_escape_string(getPostParameter('password'));
    $ip         = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");

    if (!($username && $pwd))
    {
        $errormsg = "Please enter username and password";
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM prcb_users WHERE username='$username' AND password='".PasswordEncryption($pwd)."' LIMIT 1";
        $result = smart_mysql_query($sql);

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0)
        {
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                if ($row['status'] == 'inactive')
                {
                    header("Location: /login?msg=2");
                    exit();
                }

                smart_mysql_query("UPDATE prcb_users SET last_ip='$ip', login_count=login_count+1, last_login=NOW() WHERE user_id='".(int)$row['user_id']."' LIMIT 1"); 

                if (!session_id()) session_start();
                $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['FirstName'] = $row['fname'];

                if ($_SESSION['goRetailerID'])
                {
                    $redirect_url = RetailerSEOurl($_SESSION['goRetailerID']);
                    unset($_SESSION['goRetailerID']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $redirect_url = "/myacount";
                }

                header("Location: ".$redirect_url);
                exit();

        }
        else
        {
                header("Location: /login?msg=1");
                exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Login form;

```
<form action="" method="post">
E-mail <input type="text" class="input2" name="username" value="<?php echo getPostParameter('username'); ?>" />

Password <input type="password" class="input2" name="password" value="" />

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="login" />
<input type="submit" class="butt" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
</form>
```

I appreciate if someone can help me how I can solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit to login.php add the page you came from:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($full_url);?>" />
```

Then in your login.php

```
header("Location: " . $_POST["redirect"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I like to do this, is by keeping a session variable 'lastpage' in which I store the URL or pageID for the current page. When you then go into the login, you can retrieve the last loaded page from the session and do a header redirect.

Answer (score 0):

As a user clicks on a login link, or submit a form to enter the sign in page, so HTTP_REFERER is set. In order to return to the calling page, please try:

```
$redirect_url = isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]) ?
  $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] : "/myacount";
//
// avoid an infinite loop: not redirect to the login page:
//
if(empty($redirect_url) || preg_match("/\/login/", $redirect_url))
{
  $redirect_url = "/myacount";
}
header("Location: " . $redirect_url);
exit;
```

This solution fits your wish "**Redirect previous page after login**". And more
it'is seducing as the visitor will pick up his interrupted tour on your website. Moreover, no additional form inputs are required, as apache server takes care for you.